# Python - Create tuple from tuple and other values

Tags: python, tuples

Let say I have a tuple like this:

```
a = (1, 2, 3)
```

I want to declare an other tuple using the tuple `a` and other values (`4` and `5` for example) to obtain:

```
b = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

---

I was thinking about `b = (a, 4, 5)`, but of course I end up with a nested tuple.

Do I have a pythonic way to do it without having to convert the tuple to a list and then making a loop?

Comment: `b = a + (4, 5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can unpack all the values from `a` inside to the new tuple and then add your values:

```
b = (*a, 4, 5)
print(b)

#output: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

pythonic 100%